# Need assistance regarding ARC concept

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In ARC environment I have an object `MyClass *mcObj = [[MyClass alloc]init]` after using it should I leave it just like that or do this `mcObj = nil;` after using it.

This object can exist in any scope like global in `viewcontroller` or just inside a method `-(void)aMethod;` please explain both scenarios.

Comment: You can just leave it like that.

Comment: You might set it to nil if you receive a memory warning and you can recreate the object, or you might set it to nil if you are keeping the pointer around but not the object (strong reference). I think you'd need to be more specific (with code) to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is - "it depends".

If you create it within a method and don't assign it to anything, then when it goes out of scope, it will be set to nil. (Actually, LLVM inserts the relevant `release` call for you).

If you pass the variable outside the function, then the local variable will still be set to nil when it goes out of scope, but if there is a strong reference to your object, it will not be released.

In general, you don't really have to think about this too much. If you want to keep an object around, then you keep a strong reference to it, otherwise you don't have to worry about retain release calls.

Comment: ... and instance variables will also be automatically released in `dealloc` (if that is what OP meant with *"scope like global in viewcontroller"*)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for replying, my class do not have dealloc implemented what will happen in this case? And if ARC handle all things by itself why we still get memory leaks and memory keep growing and not getting released?

Comment: @Abizem Thanks a lot for replying, please view the latest comments.

Comment: strong referenced objects will be around then how they will be released? ARC will also take care of it?

Comment: @S.J: Instance variables are automatically released when the object is destroyed, even if you don't implement dealloc.

Comment: @MartinR for strong reference do I have to set nil?

Comment: @S.J: We cannot guess why you have memory leaks. You can use Instruments to find them.

Comment: @S.J There is a difference between a memory leak - which is when you no longer have a pointer to an object that you can send a `release` message. and wasted memory - which is where you are holding on to objects that you don't need. It isn't the former you are looking for, but the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You write like:

```
MyClass *mcObj = [[MyClass alloc]init];
```

So hoping it's a local variable, inside the function.

In both cases, when you write `mcObj = nil;` The object will be released and set to nil.

It's equivalent of:

```
[mcObject release];
mcObj = nil;
```

In non-arc mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it like that!

ARC will take care of it!
ARC will release/retain it wherever it finds best to do so.